# Searching two columns and having them treated like they're one column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I build this application that does a search for a certain column(a). Turns out the data that is going in column(a) needs to be split up into to columns. Unfortunately this makes my searching mechanism messed up. Before I would do something like this.

`columnA like '%" & q & "%'`

I need the search now split into two columns, but still treated as if the data still is in one column (concatenated).

`columnA+columnB LIKE '%" & q & "%'`

Is this possible?

Comment: Better use `ISNULL(columnA, '')+ISNULL(columnB, '') LIKE '%" & q & "%'`

Comment: should there be a space between `columnA` and `columnB` or is that inherent within the data?

Comment: No space between the two. Also, i tried this solution, i think it might be working but can't really tell because the result doesn't come to me as concatenated. another words, i should get columna+b as if it was one result: columnab. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if I understand your question:

```
SELECT 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(1024),(ISNULL(columnA,''))+CONVERT(nvarchar(1024),ISNULL(columnB,''))  
FROM searchTable
WHERE 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(1024),(ISNULL(columnA,''))+CONVERT(nvarchar(1024),ISNULL(columnB,'')) LIKE '%" & q & "%'
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Error: Concat is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: @Damien see the update, I'm not sure which version sql-server introduced concat.

Comment: Saw the update. here's how i responded to the other fellow who wrote that response: tried this solution, i think it might be working but can't really tell because the result doesn't come to me as concatenated. another words, i should get columna+b as if it was one result: columnab. Any ideas?

Comment: So instead of `select *` you need to `SELECT  CONVERT(nvarchar(1024),(ISNULL(columnA,''))+CONVERT(nvarchar(1024),ISNULL(columnB,''))`

Comment: @Damien also, I'm not sure what datatypes your columns are, so you will need to replace the convert (or cast if you use it) to use the appropriate type.

Comment: @Damien "the result doesn't come to me as concatenated" <- see update

Comment: k.... that actually seems to be working. Do i need to convert? They're both varchar(255). Also, is that isNull necessary?

Comment: @Damien ISNULL ([well, I prefer COALESCE](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/)) is necessary if the columns are nullable. Otherwise, columnA = 'foo', columnB = NULL, columnA + columnB = NULL, not 'foo'.

Comment: @Damien correct, you do not need convert if the datatypes are both varchar(255)